Find duplicated nodes in equivalent paths in neo4j
The following graph models Things that are linked by Joiner nodes, where each Thing activates one or more Joiners and each Joiner targets one or more other Things.
CREATE (a: Thing {name:"a"}), (b: Thing {name:"b"}), (c: Thing {name:"c"}),
    (d: Thing {name:"d"}), (e: Thing {name:"e"}),
    (f: Thing {name:"f"}), (g: Thing {name:"g"}),
    (w: Joiner {name:"w"}), (x: Joiner {name:"x"}),
    (y: Joiner {name:"y"}), (z: Joiner {name:"z"}),
    (a)-[:activates]->(w)-[:targets]->(b),
    (a)-[:activates]->(x)-[:targets]->(b),
    (c)-[:activates]->(y)-[:targets]->(d),
    (e)-[:activates]->(z)-[:targets]->(f),
    (z)-[:targets]->(g)

In this graph:

Thing A has two joiner nodes that both target Thing B
Thing C has one joiner node that targets Thing D
Thing E has one joiner node that targets Thing F and Thing G

Ultimately I want to merge any duplicated Joiner nodes. In this case that would be W and X.
How can I find these duplicated Joiner nodes?

This query will find all extra "duplicate" Joiner nodes and delete them and all their relationships:
MATCH (t1:Thing)-[:activates]->(j:Joiner)-[:targets]->(t2:Thing)
WITH t1, t2, COLLECT(j) AS js
WHERE SIZE(js) > 1
UNWIND TAIL(js) as unwanted
DETACH DELETE unwanted

This query only has to match each Joiner path once.

Thanks for this. I profiled this answer and also @finbar good's answer against my live dataset (approx 1.5m nodes, 3.2m relationships). Your approach took 2920750 total db hits in 35866 ms. and 2920750 total db hits in 37449 ms. Which is indeed faster than the version with the EXISTS clause. That one took 4402210 total db hits in 62704 ms. and 4402210 total db hits in 71963 ms.

To find the duplicates:
MATCH (a:Thing)-[:activates]->(x:Joiner)-[:targets]->(b:Thing) 
WHERE EXISTS { (a)-[:activates]->(y:Joiner)-[:targets]->(b) WHERE x <> y} 
RETURN x

To remove all but one of the duplicates:
MATCH (a:Thing)-[:activates]->(x:Joiner)-[:targets]->(b:Thing) 
WHERE EXISTS { (a)-[:activates]->(y:Joiner)-[:targets]->(b) WHERE x > y} 
DETACH DELETE x


Due to the EXISTS conditions, these queries require an additional path search per matched Joiner path. It would be more efficient to just find all the Joiner paths once, and then use aggregation to filter for duplicates.

Thanks for the answer. It worked very well functionally, so I profiled it to compare with @cybersam 's version. Results from this one on my live dataset (1.5m nodes, 3.2m relationships): 4402210 total db hits in 62704 ms. @cybersam approach took 2920750 total db hits in 37449 ms. Amazing how much difference the EXISTS part makes.
